# Receive Ethereum payments on eCommerce website

Tags: go-ethereum

I am working on receiving ether on existing ecommerce site. For whatever reason, a decision has been made to run Ethereum node locally and not use any existing payment gateways.

I am relatively new to Ethereum. Based on what I read across forums, I can think of 2 possible approaches:

Approach 1:
For each eCommerce transaction on website, create a new contract and hand over its address to the customer to make payment to.
Periodically check balance on the contract address, if balance is > 0 - this implies that payment has been made.
Send payment from contract address to another main account address to consolidate payments.

Approach 2:
For each eCommerce transaction on website, create an account private key + address and hand over its address to the customer to make payment to.
Periodically check balance on the above address, if balance is > 0 - this implies that payment has been made.
Send payment from contract address to another main account address to consolidate payments.

I am wondering if approach 2 is even worth considering. I am looking for some expert guidance here on how best to do it, given the restriction that local Ethereum node is to be used.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

What requirements do you have, apart from just being able to receive ether? If there are none, you only need an address. Run the node, give customers the address, let them pay. Does not differ much from accepting Bitcoin. If you want to track payments (e.g., differentiate between new and returning customers), you can do that off-chain (either using some wallet feature or parsing the blockchain with a common programming language like Python).

You only need a smart contract if you want to implement more complex logic, for instance, automatically rewarding customers with tokens, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to find out which customer made the payment and the amount paid by the customer. If everyone is paying to the same customer - how will I be able to differentiate?
Can you please point to some examples of tracking payment off-chain that you have mentioned? Will I be able to find out the customer who has made the payment?

Comment: @Kevin by looking at the "from" and "value" fields on the blockchain ([example: random address at etherscan explorer](https://etherscan.io/address/0x3de8c14c8e7a956f5cc4d82beff749ee65fdc358)). That of course does not work if the customer uses another address next time -- but in that case a smart contract won't help either. In Ethereum world the Bitcoin-style "fresh address for every tx" practice is not so common, as smart contracts use addresses for authentication.

Comment: Thanks again for your quick reply. However, I cannot think of a way to link my customer with the "from" address. Is there a way to know?
The only way I could think of it by giving each customer a unique contract address - same as bitcoin approach.

Comment: @Kevin The simplest approach that comes to mind is to make it beneficial for the customer, e.g., "get 5% off on your second order (use same address so that we can recognize you)". Or users can register and log in, so that you show the address corresponding to the internal user ID in your system.

Comment: I still do not see how can I link the first payment with the  customer, I need to know which customer in my system has made payment - so that the particular order can be shipped.

Comment: Shafeshift uses the second approach, it generates a new address for each operation and waits for the user to make a deposit in 10 minutes, and then wait for 12 confirmations. It has a UI where the user can track the payment status, ie waiting, received, confirmed, etc.  Another approach I've seen is to generate a `code` and tell the user to put it in the `input` field of the wallet, the problem with this approach is not all wallet show that field, or they use other names like `data`, or `extraData` which is confusing.

Comment: A third approach is to have different prices for each customer. For example if they have to pay 1 ether make them pay 1.00001 for first customer, 1.00002 for second. (The rent in my building uses a system like this, where the cents is your apartment number).

Comment: @Ismael - Thanks for your reply. Good to validate the second approach. Unfortunately, in our scenario we cannot use the different amount approach.
Between the two approaches I have outlined - #1 seems better as it does not generate a private key for each address and avoids managing all the private keys for each purchase.
What are your thoughts?

Comment: Using a contract in your situation seems overkill. As Sergei stated in his answer a contract is often used for complex operations. Contracts cannot be updated, once you deploy it you cannot fix it, so you have to pay for an audit it to be sure it will work as intended. Contract are used mainly when you do not want a centralized operation.

Comment: Got it. My only concern is in managing the private keys associated with the addresses for each order in second approach. 
Eventually, we will need to move the ether on those addresses to another "single" address. I understand that keys will be managed by Ethereum node, but if the Ethereum node server crashes and if I loose the keys associated with those addresses linked to orders - then I will loose associates ethers as well.
On another note, which one is more costly option? Is there "gas" required to deploy a contract?